# IONIC 4 : content.scrollToPoint is giving an error as Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of null

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using scrollToPoint as below to scroll to a specific point in my component.

```
@ViewChild(IonContent) content: IonContent;

this.content.scrollToPoint(0, yOffset - 70, 1000);
```

But it is giving an error like

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'scrollTop' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of
>   null

Can anyone please suggest me anything on this?

Comment: can you give clarification how you got the value of yOffset.

Comment: @Amine99  I have got yOffset as yOffset = document.getElementById('alp').offsetTop;

Answer (score 3):

Because the dom is not yet ready. It’s just the platform. use ionViewDidEnter event handler.

```
      ionViewDidEnter() {
        let yOffset = document.getElementById('alp');
        this.content.scrollToPoint(0, yOffset - 70, 1000);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but its Content and not IonContent in the viewChild